# value in range for big datasets

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have a problem that I can't seem to solve. I want a query to determine whether a given value lies within a predefined range, but my loop is very slow for big datasets. Is there a more efficient way?

```
clear all
close all

Regression(1,1) = 1.001415645694801;
Regression(1,2) = 0.043822386790753;

FF_Value(:,1) = [24.24 30.77 31.37 29.05 29.20 29.53 29.67 27.78];
FF_Value(:,2) = [24.16 30.54 31.15 29.53 29.39 29.34 29.53 28.17];

FF_Distance = FF_Value(:,2)-(Regression(1,2)+Regression(1,1)*FF_Value(:,1));

FF_Distance_Positiv = sort(FF_Distance(FF_Distance > 0));
FF_Distance_Positiv(FF_Distance_Positiv == 0) = [];

FF_Distance_Negativ = sort(FF_Distance(FF_Distance < 0),'descend');
FF_Distance_Negativ(FF_Distance_Negativ == 0) = [];

A = repmat(FF_Distance_Positiv,length(FF_Distance_Negativ),1);
B = repmat(FF_Distance_Negativ',length(FF_Distance_Positiv),1);
C = reshape(B,[length(FF_Distance_Positiv)*length(FF_Distance_Negativ),1]);

Recognition(:,1) = A;
Recognition(:,2) = C;

FF_Recognition = zeros(length(FF_Value),1);
for i = 1:length(Recognition)
    for j = 1:length(FF_Value)
       if (Regression(1,2)+Recognition(i,1))+Regression(1,1)*FF_Value(j,1) >= FF_Value(j,2)     &&...
            (Regression(1,2)+Recognition(i,2))+Regression(1,1)*FF_Value(j,1) <= FF_Value(j,2)
        FF_Recognition(j,1) = 1;
    end 
end
end
```

Comment: no, zeros would also be ok :)

Comment: `@Mario`what is your ideal "big" dataset?

Comment: `@Mario`         Your last if condition in the `for` loop has parentheses misbalance (I think). I will be doing it my my matlab script, but could you confirm and edit the snippet please? Also, you are ending for and if conditions with `;`....don't do that.

Comment: yes of course I will do it

Comment: `@mario`        You have already preallocated your result matrix `FF_Recognition` to fasten processsing. I would advise you see if you can write 1) A Script for generating data i.e. your FF_Value and anthing that is data-related. 2) Write a function that will call the script to generate data and use that to calculate FF_Recognition and return the result. These are some know techqniques to fasten your MATLAB prgorammes. Also, if you do the `float(zeros(length(FF_Value),1))` instead of NaN, that works too. Try and run a profiler on the new code and compare to see how much has improved!

Comment: Why do you even have the inner loop? Do the comparison for the whole vector at once, no?

Comment: See if the posted solution works for you?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of **[`bsxfun's`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)** replacing your world  of **`repmats`** -

```
%------------ Original code -----------------------------------------

FF_Distance = FF_Value(:,2)-(Regression(1,2)+Regression(1,1)*FF_Value(:,1));

FF_Distance_Positiv = sort(FF_Distance(FF_Distance > 0));
FF_Distance_Positiv(FF_Distance_Positiv == 0) = [];

%// Note for Performance: If number of elements satisfying `FF_Distance_Positiv == 0`
%// is a lot, consider doing this instead - 
%// `FF_Distance_Positiv = FF_Distance_Positiv(FF_Distance_Positiv~=0)`.
%// Follow this strategy for `FF_Distance_Negativ` too.

FF_Distance_Negativ = sort(FF_Distance(FF_Distance < 0),'descend');
FF_Distance_Negativ(FF_Distance_Negativ == 0) = [];

%------- Added vectorization replacing `repmats` and nested loops ------------

mult = Regression(1,1)*FF_Value(:,1);

y1 = bsxfun(@plus,Regression(1,2),FF_Distance_Positiv);
y2 = bsxfun(@plus,y1.',mult); %//'
mc1 = bsxfun(@ge,y2,FF_Value(:,2));

z1 = bsxfun(@plus,Regression(1,2),FF_Distance_Negativ);
z2 = bsxfun(@plus,z1.',mult); %//'
mc2 = bsxfun(@le,z2,FF_Value(:,2));

FF_Recognition = all([any(mc1,2) any(mc2,2)],2);
```